# Save PDF file automatically in new folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro to create a folder within the folder where the Excel file is:

```
Sub Folder_Test()
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Folder_01", vbDirectory) = "Folder_01" Then
        MsgBox "Folder already exists!"
    Else
        MkDir Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Folder_01"
    End If
End Sub
```

And I have the following macro to create a PDF file:

```
Sub Button_PDF_200()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Now I want that the PDF file which is created in the second macro will be saved in the folder which is created in the first macro.

Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: There are tons of similar questions in the web. You can try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219784/vba-print-to-pdf-and-save-with-automatic-file-name?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just that?

```
Sub Button_PDF_200()
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Folder_01" & "\" & "test.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

---

That is changing the `Filename` argument within the sub `Button_PDF_200` from

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.pdf"
```

to

```
ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Folder_01" & "\" & "test.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

..
Hi Michi,

also you can try something like this:

```
    pdfName = ActiveSheet.Range("T1")
    ChDir "C:\Temp\" 'This is where youo set a defult file path.
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(pdfName, _
    fileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
    If fileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:= _
        fileSaveName _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If
    MsgBox "File Saved to" & " " & fileSaveName
```

Have fun!